# How to pull multiple ELB details instead of one

Tags: aws-cli

I'm trying to retrieve ELB information using below command, which was successful..

But now i would like to retrieve the same information  for multiple ELB's, please help me to retrieve information from a list of ELB's

`aws elb describe-load-balancer-attributes --region eu-west-1 --load-balancer-name **ELB_Name** --query 'LoadBalancerAttributes.ConnectionSettings.IdleTimeout`

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do something like this:

```bash
export AWS_REGION=eu-west-1

elbs="$(aws elb describe-load-balancers \
  --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[*].[LoadBalancerName]' \
  --output=text)"

for elb in $elbs ; do
  aws elb describe-load-balancer-attributes \
    --load-balancer-name "$elb" \
    --query 'LoadBalancerAttributes.ConnectionSettings.IdleTimeout'
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One small suggestion - it is better to use `AWS_REGION` and not `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`, this is because if `AWS_REGION` is defined in the user's shell it will override `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`.